# Mongoid all_in with double values in array

Tags: mongoid

I have a model `Song` which has a `all_genres` field that contains an array or values, for example: `["pop","jazz","blues"]`

The tricky part: it may also contain(this is intended) data like: `["pop","pop","blues"]`

In my query model i select songs by:

`Song.all_in(:all_genres => ["pop","blues"])`

this works fine, what doesnt it this:

`Song.all_in(:all_genres => ["pop","pop","blues"])`

It should return all songs with double `pop` and `blues` in `:all_genres`, instead I get the same results as if I would query this:

`Song.all_in(:all_genres => ["pop","blues"])`

Can anyone give me a hint? I'm sure this is possible with mongoid somehow

Comment: That works as designed to the underlying MongoDB operation. The "hint" is if your specifically want results only with 2 instances of "pop" then you would need to "count the instances" in order to get the matched result.

Comment: thanks for clarifying. solved it the problem before the query happens to sort it out.